# Настройки Java на Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Здравствуйте. У меня часто возникают проблемы OutOfMemory... PermGen.
Принцип работы приложения заключается в том, чтобы по запросам пользователя генерировать документы (Excel, PDF, ...) и отправлять на страницу пользователю для закачки.
Приложение написано на JSF, JPA (провайдер Hibernate).
Что тут можно сделать?

**Добавлено.**

Вот код, который выдает на выход сгенерированный документ:

```
public void prepareDocument() 
    throws IOException, DBUtilException, MartixOfTestResultException, NotResultsForGeneratingException {

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
    //todo Говорим документу, что это приложение/ открывать при помощи приложения.
    response.setContentType("application;");
    //todo Берем документ в виде байтов
    byte[] fileContent = getByteArrayOutputStream().toByteArray();
    response.setContentLength(fileContent.length);
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Book.xls");
    ServletOutputStream out;
    try {
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        out.write(fileContent);
        out.flush();
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Подозрение мое падает только на этот метод.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В общем, как Вы уже поняли, JVM больше не может получить памяти от ОС для Вашего процесса. То есть Ваш код что-то такое делает, что жутко потребляет память.

Вариантов несколько.

1. Действительно требуется очень много памяти (создается огромный массив, жутко наполняется коллекция);
2. Вы имеете в коде ошибку, которая приводит к потерям памяти (рекурсия без выхода, бесконечный цикл, фатальные остановы нитей устаревшим методом stop() в классе Thread, открытие большого количество потоков: файла и т.п.).

Первый вариант, я думаю, Вы рассматривали в первую очередь. Правда, если для того же самого экспорта данных в Excel и другие формы, Вы используете какие-то экзотические библиотеки, проблема может быть в них.

Второй вариант тоже возможен, изучите Ваш код или выложите ключеые фрагменты здесь. Ищите дыры: потребители ресурсов. Обратите внимание, создаете ли свои нити?

Comment: Да, действительно, создается несколько жутко огромных массивов, генерится в файл и выдается на выходе. Где-то два массива в среднем по полторы тысячи записей (ArrayList). Потом еще память забирает сам сгенерированный документ. Но проблема все-таки довольно своеобразная:  После всех работ, на следующий день, сервер все равно висит. Т.е. по логике, после того, как закончилась всякая работа на сервере, память очищается. Но нельзя зайти ни на какую страницу, и приходится перезагружать Apache.

Comment: Ситуация конечно специфическая. Дело в том, что PermGen это область для хранения классов.
Возможна ли ситуация, что контекст для контейнера был изменен или постоянно меняется? Как будто Tomcat пытается передеплоить контекст, но при этом остаются какие-то нити или происходит какое-то длительное исполнение методов еще из старых классов (из контекста до изменения).
Рекомендую сделать проифилировку Вашего приложения, чтобы посмотреть кто ест ресурсы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мой уровень знания программирования явно ниже Вашего. Мне до конца не понятно, что Вы хотели мне сказать.
Я не понял, что такое контекст для контейнера.<br><br>

Я иногда забрасываю .war файл, Tomcat его загружает и использует. Но, по-моему, когда Tomcat перегружает файлы приложения, все процессы останавливаются и удаляются.
Даже если и что-то съедает много ресурсов, почему тогда вылетает ошибка OutOfMemory после нескольких часов простоя, когда по-идее, вся память должна быть очищена от лишнего мусора?

Comment: Все верно. Когда вы меняете war-файл, контейнер (Catalina компонент Tomcat-а) пересоздает контекст (как бы окружение для war). В этот момент перезагружаются классы. Если в Вашем коде или в коде библиотеки работают какие-либо нити, эти нити при таком редеплое могут остаться рабочими, "ухватив" старые версии классов, и есть ресурсы.

Профилировка - это средство, позволяюще сделать "срез" работы JVM. Виртуальная машины предоставляет различную телеметрию: какие нити работают, сколько объектов, какие методы, сколько памяти, сколько CPU и времени и т.п.

В какой среде Вы разрабатываете?

Comment: IntelIj IDEA. В принципе, если это из-за замены, то как можно сделать срез работы JVM?<br>
И, если я правильно понял, остатки рабочих операций уже не очищаются сборщиком мусора? Если так то, видимо, проблема заключалась именно в этом.<br>
Просто в коде нет навечно зацикливающихся операций.<br>
И при работе двух человек, Tomcat берет дополнительно памяти максимум на 15 мегабайт (приложением не пользуются больше двух-трех человек одновременно). Когда как я выделил под Tomcat 1024mb.<br>

Comment: И еще: СПАСИБО ОГРОМНОЕ! Я даже не знал в какой стороне искать проблему. Видать в гугле просидел бы битых уйму времени.

Comment: Я был рад помочь. Я не знаю какие средства профилировки есть в Intelij IDEA. Я приведу пару ссылкок на статьи, где можно посмотреть как профилировать Tomcat при помощи VisualVM:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890431/profile-tomcat-application-with-visualvm,
http://blog.mattwoodward.com/monitoring-tomcat-with-java-visualvm. Данное средство позволяет также мониторить состояние PermGen.

Answer (score 1):

Основная проблема в том, что закончилась память в tomcat, попробуйте выдавать не весь массив сразу, а пачками.

Например, попробуйте заменить на:

```
public void prepareDocument() 
    throws IOException, DBUtilException, MartixOfTestResultException, NotResultsForGeneratingException {

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
    //todo Говорим документу, что это приложение/ открывать при помощи приложения.
    response.setContentType("application;");
    response.setContentLength(fileContent.length);
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Book.xls");
    ServletOutputStream out;
    try {
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        getBytArrayOutputStream().writeTo(out);            
        out.flush();
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Т.е не заносить сразу в массив байтов, а писать напрямую в out? Да, гениально. Как-то я сразу так не догадался. Спасибо.

Comment: Но я уже понял, что проблема не в большой генерации документов, а в чем-то другом. Tomcat забирает не больше 400 метров при большой загруженности. Мне надо, видимо, все-таки делать как предложил nantipov - профилировку приложения. Хотя, может еще и сборщик мусора вызывать насильно?

Comment: Может и поможет, проблема не в этом коде, а в системе в целом.

Comment: А скажите, пожалуйста, если написать<br> ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray =  getBytArrayOutputStream()<br>
byteArray будет иметь ссылку на этот стрим?

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте параметр в запуск tomcat'а (можно больше 256, мне хватило этого объема):

> -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

Comment: У меня 512 и вроде еще 1024 пробовал.